# Save primary ID in another column in MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

i have this MySQL Table:

```
    CREATE TABLE web_media_com (
    web_media_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    web_media_position INT(12),
    web_media_headline VARCHAR(76),
    web_media_description VARCHAR(680)
    );
```

I would like to add the primary id to the "web_media_position" in one INSERT INTO query. So when "web_media_id" gets the id 234 then "web_media_position" should get the same 234 number.

Right now i have this:

```
    $mysql_query = "INSERT INTO `web_media_com` (web_media_position, web_media_headline, web_media_description) VALUES
    (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$web_media_headline."', '".$web_media_description."')";
```

But this does not work. Can someone please tell me how i can do This? thanks!!!

Comment: You can't get LAST_INSERT_ID() from within the current query, you will have to run a new query and update the row.

Comment: why would you want 2 fields in the same table to be identical?

Comment: Hi! I would like to change the order which the items are get displayed ;)

Comment: @Thorsten maybe it easier for you to create a new tbl with the structure you want then insert the data from old table and the switch the table names

Comment: then just run a subsequent query to update the field

Comment: If you were sure that the ID fields were sequential you could guess the next ID number with a subquery (select count(*)+1 from web_media_com) .... join back to this and insert this value.. very messy though.

Comment: Thanks! But i think i would prefer a new query then, any ideas which is the best way to do that?

Comment: If your position can change you should assume that, for whatever reason, this can be higher or lower than the auto increment(e.g. deleting items). I'm not a query expert but I would suggest first querying for the highest position and just add 1.

Answer (score 3):

Use a transaction to prevent conflicts between concurrent inserts.

In straight (non PHP) sql it would look something like:

```
START TRANSACTION;
   INSERT INTO web_media_com(columns)....
   SET @entry_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   UPDATE web_media_com set web_media_position = @entry_id 
      where web_media_id = @entry_id;
COMMIT;
```

(NOTE: I didn't try this is in a fiddle.. YMMV...)

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution For You

```
$mysql_query =
 "INSERT INTO web_media_com 
    (web_media_position, web_media_headline, web_media_description) 
    select MAX('id')+1,'".$web_media_headline."','".$web_media_description."' 
      from web_media_com";
```

Comment: This won't work. If the last entry was deleted then MAX('id')+1 is not the same as the autoincremented counter value